# How to set Condition for multi .find and .each in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok I have following data:

```
id|name |class    |attendance
 1|Jane | 'One'   |   14 
 2|John | 'One'   |    0
 3|Jude | 'One'   |    4
```

My code is

```
$(document).find('.class, .attendance').each(function(){
    if(get class.text == 'One'  && attendance >0){
        //do something
     }else{
       //do something 
   }
});
```

What I am unable to do is, how to get get class and attendance data of same row and do the condition.

Comment: Is the data a table?

Please include the actual rendered table.

Comment: But you will most likely have to loop over each (tr or row) depending on your code and then find the class and attendance

Comment: Ok so If I loop through tr the am I able to get class & attendance?

Comment: I theory yes, but it will be much easier to give you a good answer if you provide the actual table struckture

Comment: The above is actual one.. consider as form name|class|attendance and after filling data these 3 inputs there is a btn which will create new form line with name|class|attendance and say class is drop down if somebody puts 'one' and atteandance as 0. for that line do a alert say attendance cannot be zero.